# make bootstrap tables mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code for my `bootstrap` table:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
              <!-- Simple Tables -->
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Simple Tables</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Order ID</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA0449</a></td>
                        <td>Udin Wayang</td>
                        <td>Nasi Padang</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA5324</a></td>
                        <td>Jaenab Bajigur</td>
                        <td>Gundam 90' Edition</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-warning">Shipping</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA8568</a></td>
                        <td>Rivat Mahesa</td>
                        <td>Oblong T-Shirt</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Pending</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA1453</a></td>
                        <td>Indri Junanda</td>
                        <td>Hat Rounded</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-info">Processing</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA1998</a></td>
                        <td>Udin Cilok</td>
                        <td>Baby Powder</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The problem is, on mobile device, it scrolls horizontally instead of making it go below it. like so:

[image]

As you can see, I have to scroll for it to show everything, while I would rather have it go downwards, so it doesn't look so bad on the mobile devices. kind of like this:

```
https://codepen.io/roshanjajoriya/pen/yrXNKo
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same technique here-

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
              <!-- Simple Tables -->
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Simple Tables</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Order ID</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td data-label="Order ID"><a href="#">RA0449</a></td>
                        <td data-label="Customer">Udin Wayang</td>
                        <td data-label="Item">Nasi Padang</td>
                        <td data-label="Status"><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                        <td data-label="Action"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Glad to know. Sometimes responsive is tricky.